# HDD or USB stick for keeping VirtualBox disk images for efficiency and durability?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance

I recently replaced a storage device and copied all my VirtalBox VMs to a large USB stick. The USB stick advertizes IO performance so I thought VMs may run efficiently out of it, but a few minutes into the VM session, I noticed a 100% usage of the USB stick on the Windows 10 host and very low IO throughput activity.

Would it be better to put the VM on a hard-disk drive? Are there some well-known or established guidelines on where to save VM files?

Comment: I do not keep anything long term on a USB stick. They are not highly durable. They are also slow. USB External drives (USB3) are better but I sill have a higher percentage of USB drive failures than local drives. I provide enough SSD drive space on my computer to keep virtual machines locally on my computer (200 GB of machines).

Comment: I'm with @John. Don't trust a USB stick as far as you can throw it. They're dog slow & will fail if you look at them the wrong way. HD for VMs is also too slow. Get an SSD & mount it to the fastest point your computer has. NVMe, USB-C, Thunderbolt, SATA.